# Ldap integration to centos phpipam

Tags: centos, active-directory, ldap, authentication

I have installed phpipam on CentOS 7 and this is currently working fine, and now i am trying to integrate ldap authentication or AD authentication so i can use domain credentials to log on to service. Is it necessary to join the server to the domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

no, just configure the ldap settings.

Comment: hi, i have tried that, and even though ports are open, this is not working. Could you give me an example of how the ldap settings should be? Thank you

Comment: So i have managed to link AD authentication, however this requires user manually created and than get the account to use AD integration. I can add groups, however the users do not carry over to the system? Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/phpipam/phpipam/issues/149